# Select column with maximum value in another column but with aggregate SUM calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For each name, I need to output the category with the MAX net revenue and I am not sure how to do this. I have tried a bunch of different approaches, but it basically looks like this:

```
SELECT Name, Category, MAX(CatNetRev)
FROM (
SELECT Name, Category, SUM(Price*(Shipped-Returned)) AS "CatNetRev"
FROM a WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN b WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.ID = a.ID
    ...
    -- (bunch of additional joins here, not relevant to question)
WHERE ... -- (not relevant to question)
GROUP BY Name, Category
) a GROUP BY Name;
```

This currently doesn't work because "Category" is not contained in an aggregate function or Group By (and this is obvious) but other approaches I have tried have failed for different reasons.

Each Name can have a bunch of different Categories, and Names can have the same Categories but the overlap is irrelevant to the question. I need to output just each unique Name that I have (we can assume they are already all unique) along with the "Top Selling Category" based on that Net Revenue calculation.

So for example if I have:

| Name: | Category: | "CatNetRev": |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 100 |
| A | 2 | 300 |
| A | 3 | 50 |
| B | 1 | 300 |
| B | 2 | 500 |
| C | 1 | 40 |
| C | 2 | 20 |
| C | 3 | 10 |

I would want to output:

| Name: | Category: |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your query references two tables but you have only shown data for one of them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you mean the internal query? It has like 7 different tables that are joined for specific WHERE conditions, I didn't think it was relevant to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

Having to guess at your data schema a bit, as you didn't alias any of your columns, or define what table a vs b really was (as Gordon alluded). I'd use CROSS APPLY to get the max value, then bind the revenues in a WHERE clause, like so.

```
DECLARE @Revenue TABLE
(
    Name        VARCHAR(50)
    ,Category   VARCHAR(50)
    ,NetRevenue DECIMAL(16, 9)
);

INSERT INTO @Revenue
(
    Name
    ,Category
    ,NetRevenue
)
SELECT  Name
        ,Category
        ,SUM(a.Price * (b.Shipped - b.Returned)) AS CatNetRev
FROM    Item AS a
        INNER JOIN ShipmentDetails AS b ON b.ID = a.ID
WHERE   1 = 1
GROUP BY
        Name
        ,Category;

SELECT  r.Name
        ,r.Category
FROM    @Revenue AS r
        CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT  MAX(r2.NetRevenue) AS MaxRevenue
                        FROM    @Revenue AS r2
                        WHERE   r.Name = r2.Name
                    ) AS mr
WHERE   r.NetRevenue = mr.MaxRevenue;
```

Comment: Please mark as answer if you found it helpful :-)

Comment: Not to split hairs, but should this be OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY?  CROSS APPLY is usually used without a condition.

Comment: I've rarely ever used CROSS APPLY without a condition. That would result in an aggregate of the entire subquery, instead of one for each row of the parent.
https://www.sqlshack.com/the-difference-between-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

you can use window functions:

```
select * from 
  ( 
    select * , rank() over (partition by Name order by CatNetRev desc) rn
    from table
  ) t
where t.rn = 1
```